# SQUID Transparent SSL proxy (no intercept)

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, proxy, squid

I know how to have squid work as a transparent proxy.  You put it into transparent mode then use your router or IPTABLES to forward port 80 to the squid port.  I would like to do the same for SSL.  Every guide I see mentions setting up keys on the squid server.  I do not want squid to actually decrypt the SSL traffic then establish a connection with the server, rather I would like squid to simply forward the SSL traffic as is.  The only thing I would like to do is be able to check the SSL request for any offending IPs and drop the packets if the destination is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Squid for that. Just add "DROP" rules in your edge firewall for new outbound connections to TCP port 443 to the "offending IPs".